# xy array in Swift performance

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-playground

I have two large (several thousand values) arrays with floats, and would like to combine them in an xy point array for further processing, eg to plot.

So right now in Xcode playground I am doing this:

```
let xArray = // read from datafile, fast
let yArray = // read from another datafile, fast

struct xyPoint {
   let x: Float
   let y: Float
}

var spectrum: [xyPoint] = []

for i in 0..<xArray.count {
    let xy = xyPoint(x: xArray[i], y: yArray[i])
    spectrum.append(xy)
}
```

Now when I run the playground, this takes a really long time to do.

Any ideas how I can speed this up?

Comment: Well not running it in playground would be a good start :) Try it in an actual release build project.

Comment: Haha, yes you are correct. In a real project the array is created instantly.

Comment: That being said, are there other (more Swift-like) approaches to do this, that might even be faster?

Comment: Note that it should be `0..<xArray.count`. Calling `reserveCapacity()` on the array helps to avoid reallocations.

Comment: Any reason why you're creating your own point struct and not using `CGPoint`?

Comment: Not really, `CGPoint` is a good suggestion.

Comment: Just a thought, do you know what's taken the most time? Instantiating the class or appending to the array?

Comment: @JAL: `CGPoint` has `CGFloat` elements which are 64-bit on all macOS and most iOS platforms. That may or may not be an issue.

Comment: Yes, the x points are `Float64`, and the y points are `Float32`, so I really need a separate struct for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the performance for various solutions to your problem. You can download my tests from [this link to github](https://github.com/Decybel07/xy-array-in-Swift-performance)

### A) Your code

```
var spectrum: [XYPoint] = []
for i in 0..<xArray.count {
    let xy = XYPoint(x: xArray[i], y: yArray[i])
    spectrum.append(xy)
}
```

### B) Zip + map ([Martin R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45511538/6756852))

```
let spectrumB = zip(xArray, yArray).map(XYPoint.init)
```

### C) Range + map (My solution)

```
let spectrum = (0 ..< xArray.count).map { i in
    return XYPoint(x: xArray[i], y: yArray[i])
}
```

### D) ReserveCapacity + append ([Duncan C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45511490/6756852))

```
var spectrum: [XYPoint] = []
spectrum.reserveCapacity(xArray.count)
for (index, value) in xArray.enumerated() {
    spectrum.append(XYPoint(x: xArray[index], y: yArray[index]))
}
```

---

### My results (in seconds)

```
            ╭──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────╮
            │       A      │       B      │       C      │       D      │
╭───────────╬══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╡
│       100 ║  0.000009426 │  0.000002401 │  0.000000571 │  0.000000550 │
│       200 ║  0.000003356 │  0.000002629 │  0.000000911 │  0.000000866 │
│       500 ║  0.000005610 │  0.000007288 │  0.000002236 │  0.000002012 │
│      1000 ║  0.000010638 │  0.000009181 │  0.000003905 │  0.000005030 │
│      2000 ║  0.000019377 │  0.000013316 │  0.000007116 │  0.000008732 │
│      5000 ║  0.000023430 │  0.000019304 │  0.000019809 │  0.000019092 │
│     10000 ║  0.000050463 │  0.000031669 │  0.000035121 │  0.000035420 │
│     20000 ║  0.000087040 │  0.000058664 │  0.000069300 │  0.000069456 │
│     50000 ║  0.000272357 │  0.000204213 │  0.000176962 │  0.000192996 │
│    100000 ║  0.000721436 │  0.000459551 │  0.000415024 │  0.000437604 │
│    200000 ║  0.001114534 │  0.000924621 │  0.000816374 │  0.000896202 │
│    500000 ║  0.002576687 │  0.002094998 │  0.001860833 │  0.002060462 │
│   1000000 ║  0.007063596 │  0.005924892 │  0.004319181 │  0.004869024 │
│   2000000 ║  0.014474969 │  0.013594134 │  0.008568550 │  0.009388957 │
│   5000000 ║  0.038348767 │  0.035136008 │  0.021276415 │  0.023855382 │
│  10000000 ║  0.081750925 │  0.078742713 │  0.043578664 │  0.047700495 │
│  20000000 ║  0.202616669 │  0.199960563 │  0.148141266 │  0.145360923 │
│  50000000 ║  0.567078563 │  0.552158644 │  0.370327555 │  0.397115294 │
│ 100000000 ║  1.136993625 │  1.101725386 │  0.713406642 │  0.740150322 │
└───────────╨──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: Wow - thanks for the benchmarks, I will try this out myself later. Looks like B and C are the way to go.

Comment: Did you compile and run the tests in the Release configuration (i.e. with optimizations)? I measured 12 *milli* seconds for 1,000,000 elements and the zip method.

Comment: @MartinR I update my answer. Now i create a "Command Line Tool" and run in the Release. You can download it from https://github.com/Decybel07/xy-array-in-Swift-performance . In these tests your solution is not very effective

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski: I never claimed that the zip solution is the most efficient, in fact I tried to explain why it is not the fasted. Using `(0 ..< xArray.count).map` is a good idea!

Comment: My results (n=10, 8750 datapoints): A: 0.003419374; B: 0.010853558; C: 0.00808398; D: 0.007784076.

Comment: @Koen In your results something is wrong because `A` can't be faster than `D`. Do you use my tests?

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski: I am using the four options above, in that order, with my dataset. I call the print function directly in each function, using the same time code as in your test code. The playground calls each function. No compiler optimizations, or whatsover.

Comment: @Koen These are not reliable time measurements, because when you run code in the main playground file, you will likely have logging enabled. This adds a huge performance hit to the code.

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski: the actual functions, including the print statements are in an external framwork that the playground is linked to. But point well taken, thanks :)

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski: fyi, these are the numbers for your program on my Mac (10000 points):   0.000070755 │  0.000046534 │  0.000060472 │  0.000061282

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to create the array of points would be

```
let spectrum = zip(xArray, yArray).map(XYPoint.init)
```

(I have taken the liberty to call the struct `XYPoint`, as Swift types
should start with uppercase letters.) This also allows to define
the result array as a *constant.*

However, it is not the fastest with respect to execution time.
Reasons may be

- `zip()`  operates on general sequences and does not take advantage
  of the input being arrays.
- `zip()` returns a `Sequence` and therefore `map()`
  does not know the number of elements which are to be created.
  As a consequence, the destination array will be reallocated several 
  times.

Therefore an explicit loop is faster if you reserve the needed
capacity in advance:

```
var spectrum: [XYPoint] = []
spectrum.reserveCapacity(xArray.count)
for i in 0..<xArray.count {
    let xy = XYPoint(x: xArray[i], y: yArray[i])
    spectrum.append(xy)
}
```

In my test (on a 1.2 GHz Intel Core m5 MacBook, compiled in Release
mode) with two arrays of 10,000 elements, the first method took
about 0.65 milliseconds and the second method about 0.42 milliseconds.
For 1,000,000 elements I measured 12 milliseconds vs 6 milliseconds.

Comment: Good suggestion using zip. (voted.) I've seen it once or twice here on SO, but forgot about it. That's the most "swifty" solution I've seen, even if it is a little slower. However, at 12 milliseconds vs 6 milliseconds for a million items I think we can ignore that and choose the cleaner, one-line solution. (A 6-millisecond difference is not perceptible. Even a 60ms difference isn't really perceptible.)

Comment: Interesting. Wouldn't it be worthwhile to make a `zip` specialized for `Collection`? (Which have a known `count`)?

Comment: I wonder if the `for (index, value) in array.enumerated()` version is measurably faster than indexing into both arrays using integer indexes?

Comment: @DuncanC: I could measure no significant difference. After running my tests multiple times, the enumerated was mostly slightly slower, but sometimes faster.

Comment: Interesting. Apple implies that the `for...in` version is significantly faster than `for i in 0..n { let x = array[i] }` version. (Fast enumeration and all.)

Answer (score 2):

Once you have 2 separate arrays, combining them is a little awkward, and there isn't a neat "Swifty" way to do it. If you had an array of structs, where each struct contained an x an y value, you could use a `map` statement to transform that array into an array of CGPoint objects (which is actually another Struct type).

You start out by telling us:

```
let xArray = // read from datafile, fast
let yArray = // read from another datafile, fast
```

It might be better to rework that code you don't show, so that instead of reading all of the x points data file, then reading all of the y points data file, you:

- read an x point
- read a y point
- create a CGPoint for that X/Y pair
- Add the new CGPoint to your output array of `CGPoint` values

Or even, restructure your code that creates the data files so that it writes a file containing an array of X/Y pairs rather than 2 separate files.

If you have 2 separate arrays, you might use a variant of for... in that gives you both an index and a value for each array entry:

```
let xArray: [CGFloat] = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
let yArray: [CGFloat] = [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1]

var output = [CGPoint]()
output.reserveCapacity(xArray.count)
for (index, value) in xArray.enumerated() {
    let yValue = yArray[index]
    let aPoint = CGPoint (x: value, y: yValue)
    output.append(aPoint)
}
```

The code above will crash if `yArray` has less values than `xArray`, and will miss the last values in `yArray` if it contains **more** values than `xArray`. A complete implementation should really do error checking first and handle the cases were the arrays have different numbers of values.

Comment: I had my answer almost finished, similarities with yours are not intended but unavoidable :)

Comment: The datafiles are external, and are two base64 encoded files that are converted to an array of either x or y points. So reworking that part is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Oh well. Use Martin R's code or my code and call it a day then.

Comment: I like the the zip version, and the difference in performance is not meaningful in most cases, so I'd probably use that.

Answer (score 1):

When you run code in the main playground file, you will likely have logging enabled. This adds a huge performance hit to the code.

I tried out your code in the question as a function. Putting the function in the main swift file for arrays of size 10000 took over 10 minutes!

I moved the function to a separate swift file in the sources folder of the playground with the same size arrays, and it finished instantly.

The code I used was from your question (within a func) rather than the optimized versions.